# DD-WRT: Tunnel repeated/bridged traffic

Tags: vpn, dd-wrt, tunnel, wireless-bridge

In my neighborhood free, public WLAN (without encryption) is available.

To avoid that sniffers can see/use my traffic, I'd like to configure my DD-WRT router to build an encrypted WiFi network. All traffic should be tunneled (VPN) and then forwarded to the public WLAN.

Is this possible? If so, how do I configure my router?

Comment: What VPN provider do you use?

Comment: Currently,  I usr my own cloud-hosted VPN server (supports OpenVPN and PPTP).

Answer (score 0):

DD-wrt supports OpenVPN in the `Services / VPN` menu.

This would perhaps best be managed server-side.  Set up the dd-wrt OpenVPN client as you have your other clients, then on the server side configuration add:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

Which will tell dd-wrt to use the tunnel as its default gateway.  You will also need to set up the server to do masquarading, to NAT the traffic from your network to the servers public IP address.

If the remote server does DNS lookups, you could also add:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS <server ip>"
```

Which will ensure the DNS lookups go via the tunnel and are handled by the server.